# WebView using Chart.js cannot convert to Bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, chart.js

I'm working on an application that, apart from other things, have a news section, where every new is a WebView, and you can share them by Intent in your social media.

Here's how I create the Bitmap from the WebView, it's working on most of the cases, but if the WebView uses the library Chart.js it only works in a few devices, in the other ones
the chart itself is completely blank (the other HTML views, like texts, are fine). If the WebView doesn't use the library Chart.js, it works on every device.

```
binding.wvContent.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
val contentBitmap = getBitmapFromView(binding.wvContent)


private fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap? {
    val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.measuredWidth,
        view.measuredHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(result)
    view.layout(view.left, view.top, view.right, view.bottom)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return result
}
```

I have the `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` line in the Android Manifest, and `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()` in the App init, as well as `binding.wvContent.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true`
before loading its Url.

Thanks!

Mauricio